# Mapping logical coordinates to graphical fails when scaling

Tags: java, opengl, coordinates, lwjgl

I encountered a slight problem with my game's rendering system when I tried to scale certain objects. I think it must be the way I map objects with logical coordinates to graphical ones on the screen.

**Renderable**

```
/**
 * Retrieve the image representing the object that should be rendered.
 * @return The image sprite representing the object.
 */
public Texture getSprite();

/**
 * Retrieve the x-coordinate where the object should be rendered.
 * @return The x-coordinate of the object.
 */
public float getScreenX();

/**
 * Retrieve the y-coordinate where the object should be rendered.
 * @return The y-coordinate of the object.
 */
public float getScreenY();
```

**Texture**

```
......
......

/**
 * Retrieve the width of the texture.
 * @return The width of the texture.
 */
public int getWidth();

/**
 * Retrieve the height of the texture.
 * @return The height of the texture.
 */
public int getHeight();

......
......
```

This system works perfectly when I draw stuff like interfaces etc, which have no logical coordinates in my game world.

Let's take a look at an object that have logical coordinates and see how I map the coordinates to graphical ones and thus causing a problem when I scale the texture when drawing.

**Tile**

```
@Override
public float getScreenX() {
    return x * width;
}

@Override
public float getScreenY() {
    return y * height;
}
```

Let's say the size of the texture for any tile is 16*16 but for some reason I want to draw it at 32*32. This will cause a problem since the tile's graphical x- and y-coordinate messes up.

**Note:** I know that I can fix this by allowing the user to set a scale when loading the image into the system but I want it to be more flexible.

**TL;DR:** How can I accomplish a better mapping between logical coordinates in the game world to graphical ones while still being able to scale when I want to? There should be a better way to map instead of letting the logical objects be in charge of their graphical coordinates.

Comment: I think you'll need to store the original `width`/`height` and use those for scaling instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. When rendering a scaled version of the image I never change any variables in the texture. It basically just is texture.getWidth()*scale, texture.getHeight()*scale

Comment: Going with your 16x16 example, you would have an `origWidth` and `origHeight` variable, and they'd both be 16. `getScreenX` and `getScreenY` would use those variables instead of the current width/height.

Comment: Ok, I think you misunderstood how my code works. Going with the 16x16 example:

width = 16
height = 16

When drawing a scaled version I retrieve those variables and multiply them with the scale. I never change the value of the variables so they are always the "original" value.

Comment: Then I guess I don't see the issue then - just use the original `getScreenX` and `getScreenY` return values? Or are you scaling by applying a viewmodel matrix?

Comment: I think it might be better if I show with a graphical example:

1. This is how it looks unscaled
http://i.imgur.com/UdUT3yT.png

2. This is how it looks when scaled at twice the size
http://i.imgur.com/y7Alqtw.png

3. This is how it should look like
http://i.imgur.com/AeSP1l2.png

As you can see in 2. the tiles overlap each other since their graphical x- and y-coordinates are not mapped correctly when the scaled version are being drawn.